# JMockit and Fest UI testing

Tags: java, tdd, jmockit, fest

I have been working on a project that has numerous UI components. Since all the components are based on the MVC pattern, they are structured as a component - public interface and factory, package protected model/view/controller.

Testing them "by hand" - using mocking tecniques is too difficult and time consuming.

So i popped in the Fest framework - http://fest.easytesting.org/.
It's simple, good and does the job.

The problem appears when I try to use both JMockit - http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/ and Fest together. I noticed that Fest uses some libraries that could collide with JMockit - reflection and assert.

When i run the test, JMockit doesn't mock the required class. I used JMockit before so I'm pretty sure it's some sort of collision between the libraries. There is no $Proxy$ generated on the mocked class, and of course, the class misbehaves.

**Mocking IS required, since I have to test the full component interaction!**

Versions:

JMockit:
0.999.8

Fest:

Fest-swing   1.2.1
Fest-assert  1.4
Fest-util    1.1.6
Fest-reflect 1.2

I have no intention to go conflict hunting by looking both libraries, so any help would be appretiated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

The test/sample code is here:

```
public interface SimpleControllable {
    void init();

    JPanel getPanel();
}

public class SimpleController implements SimpleControllable {

    private final SimpleForm simpleForm;
    private final SimpleModel simpleModel;

    public SimpleController(
            final SimpleForm simpleForm,
            final SimpleModel simpleModel
    ) {
        this.simpleForm = simpleForm;
        this.simpleModel = simpleModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        simpleForm.init();

        //This works!
        /*simpleForm.getTestButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                simpleForm.getTestButton().setText(simpleModel.getSimpleValue());
            }
        });*/

        //This doesn't!
        simpleForm.getTestButton().setText(simpleModel.getSimpleValue());
    }

    @Override
    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return simpleForm.getTestPanel();
    }
}


public class SimpleModel {

    private final SimpleServable simpleServable;

    public SimpleModel(final SimpleServable simpleServable) {
        this.simpleServable = simpleServable;
    }

    public String getSimpleValue() {
        return simpleServable.getValue();
    }
}

public interface SimpleServable {
    String getValue();
}

public class SimpleService implements SimpleServable {

    private String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class SimpleForm {
    private JButton testButton;
    private JPanel testPanel;

    public void init() {
        testPanel.setName("testPanel");
        testButton.setName("testButton");
    }

    public JButton getTestButton() {
        return testButton;
    }

    public JPanel getTestPanel() {
        return testPanel;
    }
}

public class SimpleTest extends FestSwingJUnitTestCase {

    @Mocked
    private SimpleService simpleServable;

    private FrameFixture window;

    @Override
    protected void onSetUp() {
        FailOnThreadViolationRepaintManager.install();

        JFrame frameUi = GuiActionRunner.execute(new GuiQuery<JFrame>() {
            protected JFrame executeInEDT() {

                SimpleControllable simpleControllable = getSimpleControllable();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");

                frame.add(simpleControllable.getPanel());
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();

                return frame;
            }
        });


        robot().settings().delayBetweenEvents(1000);

        // IMPORTANT: note the call to 'robot()'
        // we must use the Robot from FestSwingTestngTestCase

        window = new FrameFixture(robot(), frameUi);
        window.show(); // shows the frameU
    }

    //Should use factory, but not neccesary for test purposes...
    private SimpleControllable getSimpleControllable() {
        SimpleForm simpleForm = new SimpleForm();

        //SimpleServable simpleServable = new SimpleService();
        SimpleModel simpleModel = new SimpleModel(simpleServable);

        SimpleControllable simpleControllable = new SimpleController(
                simpleForm,
                simpleModel
        );

        //Initialize the component, therein lies the problem...
        simpleControllable.init();

        return simpleControllable;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        //Before
        new Expectations() {
            {
                simpleServable.getValue();
                result = "TEST";
            }
        };

        //When

        //This works!
//        window.panel("testPanel").button("testButton").click().requireText("TEST");

        //This doesn't!
        window.panel("testPanel").button("testButton").requireText("TEST");

        //Then
    }
}
```

It seems that I blamed the framework too early. But I still don't understand the details why it doesn't work. The class *Service* IS mocked, and it should still be usable, even after delaying the expectations. I understand the time problem(initialization of the component), but have no idea how to "fix" this.

Thanks.

**UPDATE2:**

Thanks, Rogerio.
You can test the component with FEST, but it doesn't really take advantage of JMockit, and there are classes that have quite a lot of methods(yes, I know - SRP, but let's try stay on this path) and would benefit greatly from a mocking framework such as JMockit. I used this before posting the question here, so you can use it yourself, and understand that this is not the way I want to go:

```
public class SimpleTest extends FestSwingJUnitTestCase {

    //This works, and I used this mechanism before, but this is without the help of JMockit.
    //If you have a lot of methods you want to mock this test turns into chaos.
    public static class MockSimpleServable implements SimpleServable{

        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return "TEST";
        }
    }

//    @Mocked
//    private SimpleServable simpleServable;

    private FrameFixture window;

    @Override
    protected void onSetUp() {
        FailOnThreadViolationRepaintManager.install();

        JFrame frameUi = GuiActionRunner.execute(new GuiQuery<JFrame>() {
            protected JFrame executeInEDT() {

                SimpleControllable simpleControllable = getSimpleControllable();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");

                frame.add(simpleControllable.getPanel());
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();

                return frame;
            }
        });


        robot().settings().delayBetweenEvents(1000);

        // IMPORTANT: note the call to 'robot()'
        // we must use the Robot from FestSwingTestngTestCase

        window = new FrameFixture(robot(), frameUi);
        window.show(); // shows the frameU
    }

    //Should use factory, but not neccesary for test purposes...
    private SimpleControllable getSimpleControllable() {
        SimpleForm simpleForm = new SimpleForm();

        //SimpleServable simpleServable = new SimpleService();
        SimpleServable simpleServable = new MockSimpleServable();
        SimpleModel simpleModel = new SimpleModel(simpleServable);

        SimpleControllable simpleControllable = new SimpleController(
                simpleForm,
                simpleModel
        );

        //Initialize the component, therein lies the problem...
        simpleControllable.init();

        return simpleControllable;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        //This works!
//        window.panel("testPanel").button("testButton").click().requireText("TEST");

        //This doesn't!
        window.panel("testPanel").button("testButton").requireText("TEST");
    }
}
```

**The question remains - does anybody know some way I could test this with JMockit, don't forget the EDT violation.**

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to any libraries used internally by JMockit or by Fest. Whatever they use, it shouldn't matter. Can you show a small test which fails? Also, version 0.999.4 is over two years old. If you can, it would be a good idea to upgrade to JMockit 1.0.

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the call to the mocked method `SimpleService#getValue()` is occurring *after* the test has completed its execution. However, JMockit only keeps a class mocked for the duration of a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the test code, which happens to call `SimpleServable#getValue()` during window construction, *before* the expectation for this method call is recorded in the test.

To fix this, simply move the `new Expectation() {{ ... }}` block to the `onSetUp()` method, putting it before the call to `GuiActionRunner.execute(GuiQuery)`.

The following simplified version of the code demonstrates it:

```
public final class SimpleForm
{
    final JPanel testPanel;
    final JButton testButton;

    public SimpleForm()
    {
        testPanel = new JPanel();
        testPanel.setName("testPanel");
        testButton = new JButton();
        testButton.setName("testButton");
        testPanel.add(testButton);
    }
}

public final class SimpleService {
    public String getValue() { return null; }
}

public final class SimpleController
{
   private final SimpleForm form;

   public SimpleController()
   {
      form = new SimpleForm();
      SimpleService service = new SimpleService();
      form.testButton.setText(service.getValue());
   }

   public JPanel getPanel() { return form.testPanel; }
}

public final class SimpleTest extends FestSwingJUnitTestCase
{
   FrameFixture window;
   @NonStrict SimpleService service;

   @Override
   protected void onSetUp()
   {
      FailOnThreadViolationRepaintManager.install();

      // Record expectations *before* they are replayed:
      new Expectations() {{ service.getValue(); result = "TEST"; }};

      JFrame frameUi = GuiActionRunner.execute(new GuiQuery<JFrame>() {
         @Override
         protected JFrame executeInEDT()
         {
            SimpleController controller = new SimpleController();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");
            frame.add(controller.getPanel());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            return frame;
         }
      });

      robot().settings().delayBetweenEvents(1000);

      window = new FrameFixture(robot(), frameUi);
      window.show();
   }

   @Test
   public void test()
   {
      // This works provided "service.getValue()" gets called *after* 
      // expectations are recorded. With the call happening during the
      // creation of the window, it must be recorded at the beginning
      // of the "onSetUp" method.
      window.panel("testPanel").button("testButton").requireText("TEST");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought that JMockit can only mock classes during the duration of the @Test method. Keep up the great work.